# How to upload blob to Parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, blob, blobstorage

I am trying to upload blob to Parse. I can get a file to upload just fine, but I am trying to upload a blob that I get from canvas after doing a crop in Javascript. The line that I use to define a new parse File to be uploaded looks like this

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File("some_file_name.png", file);
```

Since the Blob Object is basically a File object without the meta attributes, I was hoping to be able to do something like this..

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File("some_file_name.png", blob);
```

But the result of this is parseFile being 'undefined'. And I thus cannot call subsequent methods to continue with the upload.

I can't seem to find any info anywhere else, and was hoping someone with a little more insight may know if I am missing something or on the wrong path. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"returning an undefined function"* or saying `Parse.File` is an undefined function? Describe your problem including any error messages **in full**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I can achieve the desired result by creating a Parse File object with the Base64 Data Url directly, instead of trying to create a Blob first.

```
var url          = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var base64       = url.split('base64,')[1];
var parseFile    = new Parse.File(name, { base64: base64 });
```

I found the answer here..

[converting dataURI to File to use in Parse - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024135/converting-datauri-to-file-to-use-in-parse-javascript)

Hope it helps someone!